# kubernetes hpa issue with metrics-server

Tags: kubernetes

I've configured a kubernetes cluster with metrics-server (as an aggregated apiserver) replacing heapster. kubectl top works fine, as do the raw endpoints in the metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 api group. HPA, however, does not. controller-manager logs show the following errors (and no others):

```
E1008 10:45:18.462447       1 horizontal.go:188] failed to compute desired number of replicas based on listed metrics for Deployment/kube-system/nginx: failed to get cpu utilization: missing request for cpu on container nginx in pod kube-system/nginx-64f497f8fd-7kr96
I1008 10:45:18.462511       1 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"HorizontalPodAutoscaler", Namespace:"kube-system", Name:"nginx", UID:"387f256e-cade-11e8-9cfa-525400c042d5", APIVersion:"autoscaling/v2beta1", ResourceVersion:"3367", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'FailedGetResourceMetric' missing request for cpu on container nginx in pod kube-system/nginx-64f497f8fd-7kr96
I1008 10:45:18.462529       1 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"HorizontalPodAutoscaler", Namespace:"kube-system", Name:"nginx", UID:"387f256e-cade-11e8-9cfa-525400c042d5", APIVersion:"autoscaling/v2beta1", ResourceVersion:"3367", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'FailedComputeMetricsReplicas' failed to get cpu utilization: missing request for cpu on container nginx in pod kube-system/nginx-64f497f8fd-7kr96
```

metrics-server spec:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
    image: k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server-amd64:v0.3.1
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: metrics-server
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /tmp
      name: tmp-dir
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: metrics-server
  serviceAccountName: metrics-server
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  volumes:
  - emptyDir: {}
    name: tmp-dir
```

controller-manager is running with

```
--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-use-rest-clients="true"
```

k8s version 1.11.3

Any ideas?

Comment: what parameters to run metrics-server?

Comment: you can see logs kubelet on node where run kube-system/nginx-64f497f8fd-7kr96

Comment: I've added the metrics-server spec to the original post - there are no errors relating to metrics-server in the kubelet logs (as far as I can see).

Comment: I understood, but if you kubelet port different from default - need added flags in args.       --kubelet-insecure-tls=true
      --kubelet-port=10250
      --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
      --v=5
      --logtostderr

Comment: Thanks for your attention to my issue. Connectivity to the kubelets from the metrics-server is fine. I'll try running metrics-server with --v=5 as you suggest and paste the logs.

Comment: ok, no problem. Waiting info for you

Comment: metrics-server logs (--v=5) here: https://pastebin.com/HAgu9kbx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181482/discussion-between-denis-a-and-dave-mcneill).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was me being stupid (and nothing to do with metrics-server).

I was testing on a deployment where the pod containers did not have any setting for CPU request.

Answer (score 0):

I will write here, in the comments inconvenient formatting.

Check you `proxy-client-cert-file` and `proxy-client-key`, open him this command, and check Subject CN:

```
$ openssl x509  -noout -text -in /etc/kubernetes/ssl/front-proxy-client.pem 


Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: hidden
        Serial Number: hidden (hidden)
    Signature Algorithm: hidden
        Issuer: CN=front-proxy-ca
        Validity
            Not Before: hidden
            Not After : hidden
        Subject: CN=front-proxy-client
```

In my case, Subject CN=`front-proxy-client`, this CN i added in kube-apiserver:
`--requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client`

Comment: I also have '--requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client'.

Comment: Also this - 

$ sudo openssl x509 -in /etc/kubernetes/front-proxy-client.crt  -text | grep Subject:
        Subject: CN=front-proxy-client

Comment: I don't have more ideas :(